Builder design pattern for API endpoint Spring Boot
I tried to use a builder design pattern for a model class. I need to have some mandatory files and some optional fields; this design could help me in this scenario. I am using Spring Boot and Java 22 and created a model class for one of the endpoints. I also included the imports, and I removed a lot of the unnecessary code since the focus is the priority field. This is the class:
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

public class ConfigRequestModel {
    private String id;
    //other mandatory fields
    private Optional<Integer> priority;
    // other optional fields


    public ConfigRequestModel(){}

    public ConfigRequestModel(ConfigRequestModelBuilder builder) {
        this.id = builder.id;
        //other mandatory and optional fields
        this.priority = builder.priority;
    }


    public static class ConfigRequestModelBuilder{
        private final String id;
        //other mandatory and optional fields
        private Optional<Integer> priority;


        public ConfigRequestModelBuilder(String id,
                                         //other mandatory fields) {
          //mandatory fields

        }

        public void map(HashMap<String, String> map) {
            if(frequency.isEmpty()){
                this.map = new HashMap<>();
            }else {
                this.map = map;
            }
        }

        public void setPriority(Optional<Integer> priority) {

            this.priority = priority.isPresent() ? priority : Optional.empty();

//            if (priority.isPresent()) {
//                this.priority = Optional.empty();
//            }else {
//                this.priority = priority;
//            }
        }

        public void date(Optional<String> date) {
            if (date.isPresent()){
                this.date = Optional.empty();
            }else {
                this.date = date;
            }
        }
    //rest of the setters

    public String id() {
        return id;
    }
   // rest of the getters
   //equals
   //hashCode
   //toString

This is how I am using the priority:
if (configRequestModel.getPriority().isEmpty())

I got this error:
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Optional.isEmpty()" because the return value of "com.upload_manager.UploadManager.model.uploadManager.ConfigRequestModel.getPriority()" is null] with root cause

It is bizarre because Jackson should call the builder by default since I have read that it can detect those patterns. Moreover, the priority.isPresent() should work and put Optional.empty(), not null.
If you have any suggestions, please feel free to share them.

"Jackson should call the builder by default" - Why should it do that when you also have a no-args constructor? Apart from that, I don't see priority being assigned in the builder when the setter isn't called.

Do not use Optional for a field (instance variable). You gain nothing by it. Just use a nullable Integer variable. (And if you wanted an optional integer, you should have used OptionalInt.)

I had to add all the optional fields as Optional.empty() in the default constructor. Thank you again @dan1st!
